# tables is not created in database

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a database for my project, named fund distribution system. When I try to create 10-15 table and while creating last two tables, the foreign key constraint is not added in the table and showing an error message.

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE `funddistribution`.`view` 
> ADD INDEX `view_email_id_idx` (`view_email_id` ASC),
> ADD INDEX `view_rep_id_idx` (`view_rep_id` ASC);
> ALTER TABLE `funddistribution`.`view` 
> ADD CONSTRAINT `view_email_id`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`view_email_id`)
>   REFERENCES `funddistribution`.`reg_off` (`reg_off_id`)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE,
> ADD CONSTRAINT `view_rep_id`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`view_rep_id`)
>   REFERENCES `funddistribution`.`report` (`report_id`)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE;
> ```
>
> ERROR 1061: Duplicate key name 'view_email_id_idx' SQL Statement:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE `funddistribution`.`view` 
> ADD INDEX `view_email_id_idx` (`view_email_id` ASC),
> ADD INDEX `view_rep_id_idx` (`view_rep_id` ASC)
> ```